# login validation realm kotlin kmm

Tags: realm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl, realm-mobile-platform

I have a simple kotlin code and I want to validate if the users credentials are right, this is the method on the repo that checks if the user is valid or not, returns the user if the credentials are correct, exception otherwise:

```
suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): User{
        return appService.login(Credentials.emailPassword(email, password))
```

This is the method from the loginview model:

```
fun doLogin(userName: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repo.login(userName, password).apply {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    _loginStatus.value = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

HOW CAN I CATCH THE EXCEPTION ON THOSE 2 COROUTINESCOPES???

This is my button and method call from the login activity:

```
 Button(onClick = {
                showProgress = true
                loginViewModel.doLogin(userName.value, password.value)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Login")
            }
```

**How do I catch the exception when the user is invalid?**

Comment: You already catch exception in the repo's `login` method by using `try-catch` block, no?

Comment: Hello Sergio, no, the method from the repo return User data type

Comment: but you had `try-catch` and nullable type was returned `User?` before, you can handle exceptions like this.

Comment: I solved by adding try catch on the view model.
I have one more question, how do I retrieve the username of an already loggged in user?
`
fun getUser(): String {
        return appService.currentUser.getUsername?
    }
`

Comment: from the realm.currentUser I can get only the identity id